# Drawing string by GDI+ in exactly in specified point

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, gdi+

I have problem with drawing string in c#

Here is my code:

```
Graphic.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
Pen pen = new Pen(brush, 2f);
Font font = new Font("Segoue UI", 15);
graphic.DrawString("2", font, brush, new PointF(0f, 0f));
```

Previously i created picturebox and i did graphic obiect from it.
The problem is that "2" is not drawing in (0;0) but in (4;5). Event if i turn off AntiAlias is still in (4;5).

I check it by drawing two lines from (0;0) to (200;0) and from (0;0) to (0;200) and according to them i calculated that error in drawing string.

Any ideas why? I need draw string in exactly point.

//Edit
i was also trying set font in this way:

```
Font font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
```

and draw "2" in (0,0), the real position of "2" is (3,3). With drawing "1" error is the same (3;3).

Comment: This is the way line-height works.

Comment: Even if i use this:  Pen pen = new Pen(brush); problem still remains

Comment: Try setting the text alignment properties explicitly as explain on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332kzs7c.aspx).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Please post a screen shot so we know what “"2" is not drawing in (0;0) but in (4;5)” means.

Answer (score 1):

`Graphics.DrawString` is automatically padding the box it uses to draw strings. The reason is that it's purpose is to draw label texts etc. for controls and therefor is "ready-made" so there is padding around the text.

Microsoft eventually realized that this approach wasn't the best for situations when one needed more accurate text drawing (ie. text editors etc.), and for that reason developed the `TextRendered` class which wraps GDI instead of GDI+ and give back the "old" more accurate string drawing.

Try:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "2", font, new Point(0, 0), brush);
```

You might experience padding even with this, but here you can more reliable compensate for that. Check the link below to see what flags you can use with the method.

Note: if you need to measure text it's important to use the `TextRenderer.MeasureText()` for this.

For more details, go to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.aspx

Flags:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3cdh3zw.aspx

Comment: Thanks for response. Flag NoPadding works, but just for left-side. So i'm drawing tekst with specified font, and i'm just checking "manualy" where is text, and then i'm calculating the drawing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

what happens if your "string" has a descending letter, like a g or a j?  each font allows for descending parts of letters, so you might need to account for that by looking at the font's metrics

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b.aspx